# Is there a way to make mouse move universal regardless of sensitivity?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouse, pyautogui, mousemove

So I dont have code because its not an issue with coding as I already have the program done and working however I noticed that:

In gaming menus mouse sensitivity doesnt matter because I set coords to click/move and since its not sensitivity related it works just fine.
However,
When moving a game camera(character view) if I do for example 'move 1000 pixels to the right' this will be affected by mouse sensitivity & ingame sensitivity is there no way to make this work in all resolutions / mouse sensitivity?

Essentially I need to be able to make my friends 'camera"/'character view' to move as much as mine while having a different mouse DPI

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving in a relative way move to a fixed point of your display for example:

```
import pyautogui
import time

time.sleep(3)

pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100)
```

This will move your mouse to 100 pixels along 100 pixels down on your monitor. Other examples:

```
# To make it drag along the screen
# (x, y, time taken)
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, 5)

# To make it hold while moving
# The 5 slows it
pyautogui.dragTo(100, 100, 5)

# To check if the next move pos is on display
# This will return false
pyautogui.onScreen(0, -1)

# To Move only x/y
pyautogui.moveTo(None, 500)
```

Allthough pyautogui should only move directional to the pixels irrespective of the DPI so may you please attach your code.